# Remove JSON root

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following string on a JavaScript variable:

```
my_Variable = "{"Domini":[{"cod_domini":"1","nom_domini":"Sant Esteve de Palautordera"},{"cod_domini":"2","nom_domini":"Parc Natural del Montseny"},{"cod_domini":"5","nom_domini":"Sant Pere de Vilamajor"},{"cod_domini":"6","nom_domini":"Santa Maria i Mosqueroles"}]}"
```

I need to remove the root at the top of string `Domini` so the resultant string looks like this:

```
my_Variable = [{"cod_domini":"1","nom_domini":"Sant Esteve de Palautordera"},{"cod_domini":"2","nom_domini":"Parc Natural del Montseny"},{"cod_domini":"5","nom_domini":"Sant Pere de Vilamajor"},{"cod_domini":"6","nom_domini":"Santa Maria i Mosqueroles"}]
```

I've tried to parse JSON to an object using `JSON.parse()` function and it works, but then I don't know how to retrieve the data and handle it to generate a new JSON without root.

Should I be using some kind of loop?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the root? Most of the times once you convert this string to JSON object anyhow you wont refer to this root.

Comment: Is the "root" always going to be named `Domini`?

Comment: Thank you very much to everybody! Actualy it was realy easy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple:

```
my_Variable = my_Variable.Domini;
```

After JSON parse.

So code will be like:

```
my_Variable = "{"Domini":[{"cod_domini":"1","nom_domini":"Sant Esteve de Palautordera"},{"cod_domini":"2","nom_domini":"Parc Natural del Montseny"},{"cod_domini":"5","nom_domini":"Sant Pere de Vilamajor"},{"cod_domini":"6","nom_domini":"Santa Maria i Mosqueroles"}]}";
my_Variable = JSON.parse( my_Variable );
my_Variable = my_Variable.Domini;
console.log( my_Variable ); // [{"cod_domini":"1","nom_domini": ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
obj = [Object.keys(obj)[0]];
var newJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

or, eschewing ES5 features like Object.keys:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
for (var key in obj) {
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) continue;
    obj = obj[key];
    break;
}
var newJson = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: (this solution works for any root - if you just want to get .Domini, then do that of course)

Answer (score 2):

Considering you want it back to a string after removing the key.

```
my_Variable = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(my_Variable).Domini);
```

---

### Breakdown

```
JSON.parse(my_Variable)
```

Parses the string into a JSON object.

```
JSON.parse(my_Variable).Domini
```

Returns the value of the property `Domini`.

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(my_Variable).Domini)
```

Encodes it back into a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your variable passed, do the following (you mentioned you had already done this, but I added it for completeness)

```
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(my_Variable);
```

when you have parsed it, just do the following:

```
var JsonWithoutDominiAsRoot = parsedJson.Domini;
```

You can "." your way through different attributes of your new json object. Domini just being one of them.